# When cooking in the crockpot is low, lower than keep warm?

Tags: chili

I was wondering if anybody knew that is low lower than keep warm on a crockpot?

Comment: Why do you want lower than "warm", which is already not hot enough to cook safely?  You've tagged this "chili", implying you're actually cooking food in it

Answer (score 3):

No, low and high are hotter settings intended to actually cook food.

Warm is a setting used to hold food that’s already been cooked (and is already hot)

**Update**: ‘warm’ may not keep the food above 140°F and out of the ‘food danger zone’. As some slow cookers just send a constant amount of energy, they do not correspond to specific temperatures (which is further dependent on what’s in the cooker, if it’s lidded, etc).

Comment: And on plenty of models, "warm" can't be regarded as holding food hot enough to be safe indefinitely.

Comment: An excellent point.  It’s a function of how much food, evaporative cooling, etc.